# Is it harder to perform a difficult act or avoid doing a compelling act?

Tags: decision-making

Suppose what we have a set of choices $S$. Also suppose that $S$ consists of two "difficult" choices $X$ and $Y$ that rely on action and inaction respectively. So $S = \{X, Y \}$. Is it more difficult to perform $X$ or to not perform $Y$?

For example, let $X = \text{asking somebody out}$ and $Y = \text{eating fast food}$. Is it more difficult to perform $X$ or to not perform $Y$?